# What is numpy.ndarray.flags.contiguous about?

Tags: python, numpy

While experimenting with Numpy, I found that the contiguous value provided by `numpy.info` may differ from `numpy.ndarray.data.contiguous` (see the code and screenshot below).

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)[:,(0,1)]

np.info(x)

print(f'''
{x.data.contiguous = }
{x.flags.contiguous = }

{x.data.c_contiguous = }
{x.flags.c_contiguous = }

{x.data.f_contiguous = }
{x.flags.f_contiguous = }
''')
```

According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview.contiguous) about a memoryview class, `data.contiguous == True` exactly if an array is [either C-contiguous or Fortran contiguous](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-contiguous). As for `numpy.info`, I believe it displays the value of `flags.contiguous`. Alas, there is no information about it in [the manual](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flags.html). What does it actually mean? Is it a synonim for `flags.c_contiguous`?

[image: experimental output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/lib/utils.py#L431) of `numpy.info`, we can see the subroutine for processing `ndarray`:

```py
def info(object=None, maxwidth=76, output=None, toplevel='numpy'):
    ...
    elif isinstance(object, ndarray):
        _info(object, output=output)
    ...

def _info(obj, output=None):
    """Provide information about ndarray obj"""
    bp = lambda x: x
    ...
    print("contiguous: ", bp(obj.flags.contiguous), file=output)
    print("fortran: ", obj.flags.fortran, file=output)
    ...
```

It returns `flags.contiguous` as the array's continuity parameter. This one isn't specified in [flags description](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flags.html). But we can find it in [flagsobject.c](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/23c05e6f1b392f80f749dbb4668b5e7b52aef014/numpy/core/src/multiarray/flagsobject.c#L459):

```c
// ...
static PyGetSetDef arrayflags_getsets[] = {
    {"contiguous",
        (getter)arrayflags_contiguous_get,
        NULL,
        NULL, NULL},
    {"c_contiguous",
        (getter)arrayflags_contiguous_get,
        NULL,
        NULL, NULL},
// ...
```

So it's clear now that a `contiguous` parameter from `numpy.info` is actually `flags.c_contiguous` and has nothing in common with `ndarray.data.contiguous`. I guess when programming in C it was natural to say just `contiguous` instead of `c_contiguous`, and this has led to a slight inconsistency in terminology.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)[:,(0,1)]
```

`np.arange(9)` produces a 1d array; `reshape(3,3)` reshapes it to 2d.  It's a `view` of the original `arange`.  Without an order parameter, `reshape` sticks with the default `c-order`.

The `[0,[0,1]]` is advanced indexing, making a copy.  Indexing with `[0,:2]` would select the same values, but make a `view`.

The `info` strides is (8,24).  The `strides` for `x` after the reshape should be (24,8), stepping by 8 bytes for the last dimension, 3*8 for first.  But the advanced indexing flips things around - that's a detail of indexing that we usually ignore (or are unaware of).

2d array with smaller first strides is `F-order`.

I won't try to decipher all the data/flats contiguous prints, but the basic layout is obvious to me from the shape and strides.  I think the strides has priority, and all the 'contiguous' displays are derivative, interpretations, so to speak, of the strides.

With 3d (or higher) arrays, the `contiguous` alternatives can break down.  It would be possible to make an array with strides like (48,8,24), where the middle dimension steps the fastest. That's neither c or f congtiguous.

I might add that unless you are doing something like

```
np.arange(9).reshape(3,3, order='F')
```

the type of contiguity is usually not something we worry about.  Some functions (esp. compiled ones) require a certain contiguity.  And some operations are faster (or slower) depending on which dimension is 'inner-most'.  But for ordinary `numpy` use I don't pay much attention to the `flags`.  I used `numpy` for years before realizing that your example indexing flipped the `order`.

You could have just displayed `x.flags`.  I'm not sure what displaying `x.data` does for you.

### edit

`x`, created in my session as `int32`:

```
x
Out[28]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 4],
       [6, 7]])

x.strides
Out[29]: (4, 12)
```

I've usually used `__array_interface__` instead of `np.info`, but the information is similar:

```
x.__array_interface__
Out[30]: 
{'data': (1175190303648, False),
 'strides': (4, 12),
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'shape': (3, 2),
 'version': 3}
```

I generally look more at the `strides` than the flags, but here's the full display:

```
x.flags
Out[31]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

Why is `owndata` False?  Apparently the indexing actually creates:

```
x.base
Out[32]: 
array([[0, 3, 6],
       [1, 4, 7]])
```

and then returns the transpose.  Transpose of a c_contiguous array is f_contiguous.

If I create the same array (valuewise) but with slicing, I get a `view` that is not contiguous in either sense:

```
y = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)[:,:2]

y
Out[34]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 4],
       [6, 7]])

y.strides
Out[35]: (12, 4)

y.base
Out[36]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

y.flags
Out[37]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

It's a discontiguous subset of the `base` values.  The `base` is the original `np.arange(...)`, not the `reshaped` result.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed this incidentally. Earlier I learned about [memoryview](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) and its `contiguous` param. It was unusual to see `contiguous: false` when `true` was expected.

Comment: `memoryview` is a relatively recent addition to python3, giving a general purpose interface to "arrays", not just `numpy`.  Its methods and attributes look a lot like the `ndarray` ones, but are not identical.  Apparently `contiguous` is True if either the `c_contiguous` or `f_contiguous` are true.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error

```
AttributeError: 'Flags' object has no attribute 'c_contiguous'
```

just make some change in the code as shown below:

```py
y_train_predict = KNN_model.predict(X_train.values) # add .values to the X_train
model_score = KNN_model.score(X_train.values, y_train) # add .values to the X_train
```

no need to downgrade your sklearn version. Just add `.values`